# jQuery include variable as class name

Tags: jquery, class, variables, filter

Running into some weird issue, can't quite figure out what's wrong. No errors popping up on my console.

I'm trying to filter my selector with a variable as it's class. See jsFiddle and below

Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/danielredwood/SUxQx/2/

JavaScript:

```
$('.titles li').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');

    var selected = $(this).attr('class').replace(' selected', ''),
            next = $('.lyrics article').hasClass(selected);

    $('#w').html(selected); //for testing, shows what the value is
    $('#x').html(next); //ditto

    $('.shown').fadeOut(400, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('shown');
        next.fadeIn(400).addClass('shown');
   });
});
```

Comment: Maybe you can describe what you're trying to accomplish.  I'm sure there's a better way than what you're doing now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure this:

```
next = $('.lyrics article').hasClass(selected);
```

...should be this:

```
next = $('.lyrics article.' + selected);
```

...since `.hasClass()` returns a boolean.

---

Or you could do this instead (gives the same result):

```
next = $('.lyrics article').filter('.' + selected);
```

---

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LaBxC/)**